# Updating and Transitioning Data on graph using D3 and Socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, d3.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to get a line graph made using D3.JS to update using data being brought in from a web socket.

I used this simple D3 Line Graph as a base: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5

I've got the socket connection with the graph, the two issues I'm getting that I can't seem to work around are as follows:

1. The graph shifts updating for a few data points and afterward continues shifting but doesn't show any new points, the axis at the bottom doesn't transition either.
2. When updating to the next point, it jumps abruptly. I've looked into how to get it to transition smoothly, but no solutions I've found have worked, only causing different errors.

```
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('data1', function(msg){

      //add data to the queue
      data.push({
       time: ++t,
       value: parseInt(msg.data)/10
     })

     tick(); 
    });


     // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
      var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
          width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var n = 40,
        random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2),
        data = d3.range(n).map(random);
        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select(".data")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .attr("id", "graph")
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform",
                      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, n - 1])
        .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-1, 1])
        .range([height, 0]);
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(10).tickFormat(function(d){ return d.x;});
    var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 120])
        .range([0, width]);
    var axis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(widthScale);

    var path = svg.append("g")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line");



    function tick() {
    //  console.log(data.length);
      // update the domains
      x.domain([t - n + 2, t]);

      // redraw the line
      svg.select(".line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null);

      // slide the x-axis left
      axis.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(x.axis);

      // slide the line left
      path.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t - n) + ")");

      // pop the old data point off the front
      if (data.length > 20) data.shift();

    }


<!-- What do you expect the result to be? -->

<!-- What is the actual result you get? (Please include any errors.) -->
```

I also get these two errors on the console if that helps:

Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…733.68421052632,NaNL-108719.7368…".

Uncaught TypeError: axis.transition is not a function

Answer (score 0):

What version of d3 are you using?  Would it happen to be 4.12?  I've started getting "transition is not a function" errors since I updated to 4.12.  Downgrading to 4.11 might resolve the problem.